# Method must have a return type WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, windows-services

I am creating windows service using WCF service library for developing TCP based communication between PIC32 Microcontroller and Windows platform to send and receive data.

My app.config file is

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1Behavior" name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

And the C# Codefor service1.cs file is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using WcfServiceLibrary1;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null;
        public WCFServiceHost1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
            }
            myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
            myServiceHost.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
                myServiceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am getting error in `public WCFServiceHost1()` that *Method must have a return type*.

I am not getting why I am having this error. I am now in WCF and I did upto this this by the information provided in the msdn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you wanted to declare constructor:

```
public Service1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

However, you have declared method that should have return type (it could also be void):

```
public WCFServiceHost1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

To sum up if it is a constructor it should be `public Service1()` (same as type name), if it is a method it should be `public void WCFServiceHost1()`.